# Hide stages that are never run in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, visualization, declarative

I have a scripted pipeline that I want to port to declarative form. I used to have

```
// Stages used in developement after each single commit
stage('Build') {
}

stage('Unit Tests') {}
// Other stages only for developer
[...]

// Stages used in test only once per day for instance
stage('Deploy') {
    if ( testJob() ) {
    } else {
        Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
    }
}
[...]
// Other stages for more testing
```

Then for the jobs that run for developers only the 1st stages of the pipeline where visible in Jenkins.
In declarative, I have:

```
pipeline {
[...]

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            [...]
        }

        stage ('Unit Tests') {
            [...]
        }
[...]        
        stage ('Deploy') {
            when { expression { testJob() }
            [...]
        }

[...]
    }
}
```

But even for the development job, I see all the stages.
Is there a way to get the same behavior as with scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding a dependency into your you jenkins, [there's this small project](https://github.com/comquent/imperative-when).

It utilizes this hidden Jenkins tool

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils
// .....
stage('I am skipped') {
    Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
}
```

And provides it as library, so after some configuration
[image: library setup]

The final usage would look like

```
stage('My Conditional Stage') {
    when (BRANCH_NAME != 'master') {
        echo 'Only on master branch.'
    }
}
```

The result would be (even the skipped stage column should disappear if no results would be present historically)
[image: pipeline with skipped stage]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is a little more specific. Currently from the same pipeline, in the Stage view or the Blue Ocen view of the job run: there is no trailing stages that were _never_ ran. In your example, it;'s not a strailing stage that never run, it's a stage in the middle. It's fine but it's not what I'm looking for.
When using declarative: all the stages are always visible even if they never have ran at all, even the trailing ones.

Comment: Have you added this dependency and tried out the *imperative when*?

Comment: It works for scripted  pipelines but not for declarative ones that is what I'm looking for.
I simply would like to have no display of stages that never run in some specific job while still using a single Jenkinsfile and this in declarative form.

Comment: That's very strange, the example with library and imperative `when` is for declarative pipelines.

Comment: This is still the top result on google, so I'll just respond to @hakamairi: No it isn't. The example in the repo of imperative-when is for scripted pipelines. You can tell because  stage ("x") { when(xx) { [steps here] } } just doesn't work in a declarative pipeline.

Comment: @Elec0: I don't remember this one anymore, what if you would do conditionally the following for your stage? ```org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional('x')``` assuming your stage name is 'x'.

Comment: @hakamairi yeah you're probably right. You'd have to wrap it in a script { } block, but that might very well work.

Comment: The answer is not too bad then @Elec0, unless you are after some other outcome.